# Web2Py using variables with db().count()

Tags: python, html, database, web2py

Ok this one should be an easy question id imagine, but cannot figure it out.

Im passing form data to the controller and attempting to do a data search there, which in turn, runs this..

```
def initLogin():
    userName = request.vars.user_name;
    counter = db(db.Users.UserName == userName).count()
    if counter > 0:
        return DIV("User exists")

return DIV("user does not exist")
```

I have checked the value is being passed correctly( which is is) by returning userName instead of the string, which shown me it was the correct value, and when i had a direct string of a correct username, it seemed to work. So my question is.. how do you run a count() function with web2py databases correctly using variables?

Comment: The above code is correct. If the `if counter > 0` statement is not evaluating to `True`, then the record in question was not found. The problem must lie elsewhere. What happens if you replace `userName` with the exact string you are passing in `request.vars.user_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and shouldn't be giving you any problems, the only possible problem should be in your `userName` var not being what you expected or an incorrect sql query. I recommend that you try changing your controller to:

```
def initLogin():
    userName = request.vars.user_name;
    counter = db(db.Users.UserName == userName).count()
    lastExecutedQuery = db._lastsql

    return DIV( lastExecutedQuery )
```

And check if the query being performed is the one that you expected.